# Chrome insists on accessing localhost through HTTPS, any way to change that?

Tags: google-chrome, https, localhost, ampps

I have a local webdev setup using AMPPS on OSX.  I've done most of my work on Firefox and that's been working fine, but trying it on Chrome today gave me a whole bunch of `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED` errors everywhere.  Looking further it seems like Chrome wants to access every resource through HTTPS.  Firefox doesn't have this issue, it access all resources through HTTP and the site displays fine.

Is there any way to force Chrome to access localhost through regular HTTP?  I've tried every solution I could find - including going to `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` and deleting localhost (localhost doesn't show up in the domain query so there's nothing to delete) - and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you list your active plug-ins and whether or not you are willing to clear browser cache, cookies, auto fill-ins and site data

Comment: I've done a full cache and data wipe, didn't help.  Don't think plugins have anything to do with this because I have the same issue on Chrome Beta and Dev on Android.

Comment: Chrome on what os and chrome version# to start with (pick one)

Comment: OSX 10.10.3 and Android 5.1.1. Chrome versions 45.0.2444.0 (desktop), 45.0.2438.3 (desktop), 44.0.2403.63 (Android), 45.0.2439.0 (Android).

Comment: Still don't have a solution for this.  Tested with Safari and that's working fine like Firefox, but all versions of Chrome I've tried keep trying to serve localhost through HTTPS.